# Express downloads file instead of using it as html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver

I am trying to make my own server with express. I am trying to serve an HTML file, but when I run res.send() on it, it downloads the file. Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
res.send(fs.readSync(path.join(__dirname, "pages/login.html")))
```

When I go to that page, instead of rendering the file, it downloads it. If this changes anything, this page is redirected to from the "/" page.

**Update:** Clearing the cache fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You, presumably, forgot to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/html` so the browser doesn’t know it is receiving an HTML document it is supposed to render.

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
```

… as per [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send).

That said, if you are serving static files, then you should probably be using [the `static` module](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) instead of rolling your own handler.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. I'm using strings because I want to add dynamic variables to html via RegExp replacing.

Comment: There are plenty of [template engines](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) that are compatible with express that are much power powerful, safer, and easier to use then reading files manually and then applying regular expressions to them.

Comment: Clearing the cache actually did it.

Answer (score -1):

Use res.end instead of res.send.

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
res.end(fs.readSync(path.join(__dirname, "pages/login.html")))
```

Or read html as string.

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
res.send(fs.readSync(path.join(__dirname, "pages/login.html"), "utf8"))
```